# Convert to ArrayList and load to Spinner?

Tags: android, json

How do i convert the following to a ArrayList ? Because i need to load this to a Spinner in android.

json string: `{"3":"APM","2":"YAZ","1":"SST","5":"IDB","4":"NCRC"}`

Comment: you can use GSON or Jackson library for JSON parsing, extract the values, put them in Arraylist of string and provide it to spinner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
private ArrayList<String> parseJsonData(String strJson) {

        ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
        try{
            JSONObject data = new JSONObject(strJson);
            if (data != null) {
                Iterator<String> it = data.keys();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    String key = it.next();

                    try {
                        items.add(data.getString(key));
                    } catch (Throwable e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return items;
    }
```

Comment: Hey i tried this way thanks a lot and i was able to load to a spinner. I want the items to be loaded in the arraylist in order of the integer value. E.g.

The string i have:

{"3":"APM","2":"YAZ","1":"SST","5":"IDB","4":"NCRC"}

The arraylist result:

[APM, YAZ, SST, IDB, NCRC] where APM is in 0 location, YAZ in location 1 and so on.

What i want:

As the string shows, APM has 3 and YAZ has 2 so the arraylist should be having APM in the 3rd location and YAZ in the 2nd location and SST in the 1st location.

Answer (score 1):

Make a class :

```
  class MyArray {
     public  ArrayList<Details > result = new ArrayList<Details>();
   class Details {
     String id;
     String value;
 }
 }
```

Then in your class :

```
      String json = {"3":"APM","2":"YAZ","1":"SST","5":"IDB","4":"NCRC"} ;
      MyClass obj = new Gson().fromJson(json,MyClass.class);

      String strID =obj.result.get(0).id ;  // value of 1st id
      String strVal = obj.result.get(0).value  // value of 1st value

      String strID2 =obj.result.get(0).id ;  // value of 2nd id
      String strVal2 = obj.result.get(0).value  // value of 2nd value
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) for parse string.

Example:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(yourString);
list.add(json.getString("1"));
```